# In his 1931 incompleteness proof, how does Godel's definition of "immediate consequence" work?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

Necessary in order to define a provabilty predicate, Godel defined the relation, $Fl(x,y,z)$ ("$x$ is an immediate consquence of $y$ and $z$").  But the definition leaves me flat.  I understand what it says, but I don't get how it is any proper or substantive characterization of "immediate consequence."  This definition can be found on page 55 of the original paper, or on page 61 of [this](https://monoskop.org/images/9/93/Kurt_G%C3%B6del_On_Formally_Undecidable_Propositions_of_Principia_Mathematica_and_Related_Systems_1992.pdf) pdf of Meltzer's translation.  It seems that $Fl(x,y,z)$ is satisfied whenever $y$ and $z$ code a conditional and it's antecedent, and $x$ codes the consequent, or else $x$ codes the universal generalization of another variable, $v$, within the formula coded by $y$.  That is, informally, according to Godel, $x$ codes an *immediate consequence* of the formulas coded by $y$ and $z$ iff either:
(Where "$@k$" expresses the formula coded by $k$.)

1. $@y$ = $@a \to @b$, for some $a$ and $b$, and $@z$ = $@a$, and $@x$ = $@b$, or else,
2. $@x$ = $\forall @v @y$,where $@v$ may or may not appear in $@y$ at all, let alone free.

According to your own lights, does this definition do the job?  Can you explain how it works?  I think this is a pretty important hinge in Godel's proof, and I can't believe he would have 'phoned it in,' so to speak.  But I can't see what he was up to with this, $Fl(x,y,z)$.  Maybe every other mode of logical consequence is in some sense equivalent to *modus ponens*?  I just don't know.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you simply objecting to the terminology "immediate consequence"? If so, I would reply that it's just terminology, and what do the words matter as long as you understand the actual definition and how it is applied in the arguments where it is used?

Comment: I've no such objections. I agree it doesn't usually matter what something's called; what matters is what it does.  The job which Godel needs done, which is the job that $Fl(x,y,z)$ was made for, is the job of identifying "immediate logical consequence."  So it's perfectly natural to call it that.  We could call it anything.  No matter what it's called, I don't understand it.  Do you mean to suggest that $Fl(x,y,z)$ makes sense to you?

Comment: *[Shrug]* a definition is a definition. I would have to see how it's applied in an argument.

Comment: *Sometimes* I can recognize that a definition is flawed in some manner... but outside of that, generally speaking I adopt a "suspension of disbelief" when reading a new definition, until I see how that definition is applied.

Comment: Are you aware of the [*completeness theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) (also due to Godel, how's that for some potentially-confusing nomenclature!) for the various proof systems of first-order logic? Basically, a separate theorem says that such small "basic proof steps" are in fact sufficient to capture all logical consequecnes of first-order axiomatic theories. The specific notion here resembles so-called **Hilbert-style** deduction systems at a glance, but there are others (e.g. natural deduction, sequent calculus).

Comment: My recollection is that, indeed, Godel is working in a system where modus ponens is the only rule of inference.

Comment: @LeeMosher  If you understand a definition only in terms of it's applications for argument, doesn't that tend to make them all into so many black boxes?  And, if the project is to understand the definition, aren't you squandering the genetic resource of what the definition itself *says?*  If I somehow couldn't conceive the expression $(P \lor Q) \equiv (Q \lor P)$, some proofs would be hard to understand, or discover.  If the expression is somehow hidden from me in a black box, then I may never have a clear and direct understanding.  Why entertain that suspension of disbelief?  I don't get it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Thanks for the suggestion, but this isn't at all what I'm looking for.  I've studied completeness, though not Godel's 1930 itself.  Of course I've read one or two detailed technical summaries.  The reason they won't work is that these proofs are all absent the self-arithmetization/Skolemization-of-the-formal-system which is the universal context of expressions in the formal system, P, of Godel's 1931.  I need to understand how it's done in the 1931 proof, not elsewhere.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Thank-you!!

Comment: "immediate consequence" means: the result of the application of one of the two rules of inference: $\text {Gen}$ and $\text {Modus Ponens}$ to one, respectively two, premises.

Comment: I did not say this was the *only* way to understand definitions. Suspension of disbelief, and focussing on applications of the definition, are *useful strategies* for understanding definitions. Mathematical writing is often very terse, and mathematical terminology is often plucked from natural language without much sympathy for the reader's intuition. It's good to have multiple strategies for understanding.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm pretty sure you're wrong about me having to write, "$@ \to$".  The $@$-function takes numbers to expressions: "$@ \to$" is nonsense.  If I missed anything, it's concatenation ("$*$").  But adding concatenation would only subtract yet more readability, without adding any pertinent technical accuracy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Welcome to Math.SE!

> Maybe every other mode of logical consequence is in some sense equivalent to modus ponens?

Yes, modus ponens is the only propositional inference rule defined in Principia Mathematica (there are also six axioms governing the connectives $\neg$ and $\vee$). Any other inferences are *derived*, their validity shown by reducing them to multiple invocations of the axioms and the modus ponens rule. One can derive all other usual forms of inference (modus tollens, constructive dilemma, etc.) in the system of Principia Mathematica this way.

Similarly, the only inference rule governing the quantifiers in Principia Mathematica is the rule of universal generalization.

Accordingly, the *immediate* consequences of two premises are the ones that follow by a single application of one of these two rules. Other consequences are not immediate, since they require multiple uses of the inference rules. This would have been a long-standing, well-understood notion to the target audience of Gödel's On Formally Undecidable Propositions of Principia Mathematica and Related Systems, so he probably didn't feel the need to comment on it further.

Note also that which inference rules you consider basic is not a "load-bearing" part of Gödel's argument: if you formulate your logic with different sets of basic inference rules that nonetheless suffice to prove everything that Principia Mathematica proves, the resulting system will still be incomplete or inconsistent.

Comment: A hearty *Thanks* to you!!  The mystery fades away!  Your answer is on point, and clear...+1

Comment: I hope I'm not being greedy, but I want to ask a follow-up:  What about modes of consequence which proceed from suppositions, such as *conditional proof* and *reductio?*  How are these handled?

Comment: @JamesKing: The general idea is that once you have _modus ponens_, you can "emulate" other inference rules with axioms. For example, you can emulate _modus tollens_ with the axiom $(P \to Q) \to (\lnot Q \to \lnot P)$: applying _modus ponens_ twice allows you to deduce $\lnot P$ from this axiom, $P \to Q$ and $\lnot Q$.

Comment: … Ultimately, in this way, you can reduce all propositional logic to just one inference rule (_modus ponens_), two connectives ($\to$ and either $\lnot$ or $\bot$) and a bunch of axioms. Wikipedia has a decent article on [Hilbert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Conjunction_and_disjunction) that goes into more detail.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen  So if I already have, $\varphi \vdash \psi$, and I want to get $\vdash \varphi \to \psi$ (with the deduction theorem unavailable), there will be some Hilbert-style deduction to provide it with transformations entirely on the right side of the turnstyle.  That's pretty neat-o.  Thanks for the reference to the Wiki article.

Comment: ... it still seems fairly mysterious ...

Comment: @JamesKing: Forms of argument that use suppositions, such as conditional proof, where one shows $P\rightarrow Q$ by assuming $P$ and using that assumption deducing $Q$, can be eliminated altogether using the [deduction theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem). The deduction theorem holds for the system of Principia Mathematica (and IIRC this is demonstrated in Vol. I of the book): the proof tells you explicitly hoe to transform the conditional proof of $Q$ into an unconditional proof of $P\rightarrow Q$.

Comment: @Z.A.K.  Thank-you, but I'm not reasoning about the PM itself; rather, I'm working within the system P (of Godel's 1931) which was built upon the Principia.  Just because something works within PA is no guarantee that it also works in P.  Otherwise, I expect Godel's paper would have been much shorter.  Does Godel define and integrate a recursive relation to express the deduction theorem for P?  Truthfully, I don't know, but if he did, I don't know how he might have gone about it.  I just don't feel like I can count on the deduction theorem, for my research purposes.

Comment: @JamesKing, Alas, I don't know what your research purposes are, and what you can count on, which makes it hard for me to answer, or even guess what you're asking precisely. If your question is "*does the deduction theorem hold for the system Goedel employs in his article?"*, the answer is an unambiguous yes. Moreover, Goedel's contemporary target audience would know this fact immediately, and would know how to write down a proof of it, because it was a completely standard, well-known technique even at the time (and is in fact given in many of the cited references in the article as well). 1/2

Comment: @JamesKing, If your question is "*is this standard algorithm that proves the deduction theorem recursive?*", the answer is again an unambiguous yes. If your question is something else, I didn't catch it :( Finally keep in mind that, as written above, the precise sorts of logical reasoning you can carry out in Goedel's system are not load-bearing as far as incompleteness is concerned. One can't get around incompleteness by adding new types of inferences: no matter what we _add_, we end up with a non-recursive system, or an inconsistent system, or an incomplete system. This is what's proven. 2/2

Comment: @Z.A.K.  Wow.  Thanks again -- you're so free with your great comments!  What I pretensiously call my "research" purposes are a motivating problematic from my decades-ago MA in logic: If there wasn't a human in the loop to startle as the systems deduction pass in front of him and then point and shout "undecideable! undecidable!" at the right time, then there would be nothing to stop the Godel sentence (G) from being provable, and so G would actually be provable (and nobody would use systems like PA and so forth).  (cont'd)

Comment: As evidence, consider that of the 46 recursive definitions laid out in that long list of his [1931](https://monoskop.org/images/9/93/Kurt_G%C3%B6del_On_Formally_Undecidable_Propositions_of_Principia_Mathematica_and_Related_Systems_1992.pdf) (pg 61), Goedel asserts that only the 46th can't be called recursive.  This is the definition for $Bew$, the provability predicate.  What's interesting, is that there's nothing in the definition of the predicate (so far as I can tell) which might render it non-recursive.  So how does it fail to be recursive?  Maybe I'm not a scholar so much as a sleuth. lol

Comment: @Z.A.K.  At this point, I'm really not asking any further questions.  Your initial answer was as much as I hoped to get in the first place.  You've been very helpful -- Thank-you!